# adding limit to my sequelize query is throwing an error

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

this works properly

```
        let data=await db.company.findAll({
            include:{model:db.user,as:'users'},
            where:{'$users.id$':7}
        });
```

but as soon as i add limit below, it throws an error

```
        let data=await db.company.findAll({
            limit:10,
            include:{model:db.user,as:'users'},
            where:{'$users.id$':7}
        });
```

here's the error when i execute the one with limit.

```
{
name: "SequelizeDatabaseError",
parent: {
message: "The multi-part identifier "users.id" could not be bound.",
code: "EREQUEST",
number: 4104,
state: 1,
class: 16,
serverName: "LAPTOP-5ED24571",
procName: "",
lineNumber: 1,
sql: "SELECT [company].*, [users].[id] AS [users.id], [users].[username] AS [users.username], [users].[name] AS [users.name], [users].[address] AS [users.address], [users].[active] AS [users.active], [users].[email] AS [users.email], [users].[phone] AS [users.phone], [users].[job_role] AS [users.job_role], [users].[time_zone] AS [users.time_zone], [users].[country] AS [users.country], [users].[currency] AS [users.currency], [users].[induction] AS [users.induction], [users].[createdAt] AS [users.createdAt], [users].[updatedAt] AS [users.updatedAt], [users].[userRoleId] AS [users.userRoleId], [users->user_company_mm].[id] AS [users.user_company_mm.id], [users->user_company_mm].[userId] AS [users.user_company_mm.userId], [users->user_company_mm].[companyId] AS [users.user_company_mm.companyId], [users->user_company_mm].[createdAt] AS [users.user_company_mm.createdAt], [users->user_company_mm].[updatedAt] AS [users.user_company_mm.updatedAt] FROM (SELECT [company].[id], [company].[name], [company].[address], [company].[city], [company].[country], [company].[state_region], [company].[logo], [company].[numberOfLocations], [company].[numberOfEmployees], [company].[audience_builder], [company].[creator_user_id], [company].[tags], [company].[createdAt], [company].[updatedAt] FROM [company] AS [company] WHERE [users].[id] = 7 ORDER BY [company].[id] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY) AS [company] LEFT OUTER JOIN ( [user_company_mm] AS [users->user_company_mm] INNER JOIN [user] AS [users] ON [users].[id] = [users->user_company_mm].[userId]) ON [company].[id] = [users->user_company_mm].[companyId];"
}
```

Any idea why this is happening? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not necessarily familiar with sequelize.js. But looking at your query statement, you have a WHERE condition in your sub query limiting it to [Users].[Id] = 7. But this doesn't exist in this part of your query context.

```
...
FROM 
(SELECT [company].[id], 
[company].[name], 
[company].[address], 
[company].[city], 
[company].[country], 
[company].[state_region], 
[company].[logo], 
[company].[numberOfLocations], 
[company].[numberOfEmployees], 
[company].[audience_builder], 
[company].[creator_user_id], 
[company].[tags], 
[company].[createdAt], 
[company].[updatedAt] FROM [company] AS [company] 
/* HERE --> */ WHERE [users].[id] = 7 ORDER BY [company].[id] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
) 
AS [company] LEFT OUTER JOIN 
( [user_company_mm] AS [users->user_company_mm] INNER JOIN [user] 
AS [users] ON [users].[id] = [users->user_company_mm].[userId]) ON [company].[id] = [users->user_company_mm].[companyId]
```

But why the query is structured as so, I can't tell. That would be something for how you've configured it/how sequalized works.